# collection in java 8

Tags: java, collections

I've got a doubt with the below code. any help will be appreciable.

```
class Test {

    static void test(List<Object> obj) {
        obj.add(5);
        obj = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(10);
        System.out.println(list);
        test(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

what will be the content of list object after test method returned to main method?

---

Expected Output:

[10] 
[] //empty

### since we are creating a new arraylist object in the same list reference which is passed to test method from main method.

Actual Output :

[10]
[10, 5]

could please explain this?

Comment: The original list still exists, just that you overwrite the reference to it in your `test` method when you reassign `obj`. The `list` variable in the `main` method still has reference to the original list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: but other than primitive datatype java methods are pass-by-reference. right?

Comment: @RaviRanjanKumar Java is *always* pass-by-value. Really, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value